# How can convert polymer2.x project to polymer3.0?

Tags: polymer, command-line-interface, polymer-modulizer

I am having some problems in upgrading a project from Polymer 2.x to 3.0.
I used `polymer-modulizer` as instructed in [upgrade guide](https://www.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/upgrade) but I couldn't find out what to input in this section:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing `Enter`, it's just asking for the name for the package you're converting, and the value inside the parenthesis is the default value if you are not inputting anything else.

Anyhow, since you are new, here are several tips for this question in specific:

1. You are asking about an extremely basic stuff, which I assume you have little to none experience working on these topics. I suggest you read and try out a lot more before asking.
2. Your question title is too broad for such a topic. You were having a  problem with what to press or input, not even any technical problem regarding the conversion.
3. Finally, learn to use Markdown more. It's helpful

Comment: Thanks for you help. I just wanted to find one who is experienced in polymer. Actually I have other problem.

Comment: Out directory: E:\MyWorks\Psd2Html\Votyup\voty-up-frontend
Unhandled Rejection at: Promise  Promise {
  <rejected> { Error: Line 53: Unexpected token !
    at ErrorHandler.constructError (C:\Users\Vanguard\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-modulizer\node_modules\recast\node_modules\esprima\dist\esprima.js:5012:22)
    at ErrorHandler.createError (C:\Users\Vanguard\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\polymer-modulizer\node_modules\recast\node_modules\esprima\dist\esprima.js:5028:27)

Comment: This is the one I really want to know. ^_^

Comment: Can't you answer to this question, Mr. Binh? :)

Comment: Seems like there are some problems in the modules `esprima.js`. Searching the same error on Google yields several results. I don't know what exactly the cause is but maybe you can check yourself. [Link 1](https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/issues/656) - [Link 2](https://github.com/jquery/esprima/issues/1718) - [Link 3](https://github.com/javascript-obfuscator/javascript-obfuscator/issues/53)

Comment: Thanks for you help. ^_^